# ServiceStack Swagger body

Tags: swagger, servicestack

I'm struggling getting Swagger to present my ServiceStack service correctly.

I would like to see an UserId string as a form parameter and a PrivateCustomer object as a body parameter, but keep getting a body parameter with BOTH the UserId and the PrivateCustomer, despite UserId also appearing as a separate input field.

Here's my code:
[image]

And here's the result in Swagger:
[image]

How do I get rid of the UserId in the body?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Api*]` annotations are only for documenting your API, they do not impact your API's behavior, e.g. the request body is always expected to be the entire Request DTO and you can't have both "form" and "body" parameter types sent at the same time, i.e. there's only 1 Request Body and when using "form" only the form variables will be sent.

If you wanted to separate them you could add `UserId` to the query string and exclude them from appearing in the model schema with:

```
[Route("/CreatePrivateCustomer", "POST")]
public class CreatePrivateCustomerRequest
{
    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "query", ExcludeInSchema = true)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "model")]
    public PrivateCustomer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

This will separate the variables and send `UserId` in the queryString and the request of the DTO in the Request Body as JSON, e.g:

```
POST /CreatePrivateCustomer?UserId=1
Content-Type: application/json

{"Customer":{"CustomerNumber":1,...}}
```

Although generally if you want required parameters separated from the Request Body you would put them in the path, e.g:

```
[Route("/CreatePrivateCustomer/{UserId}", "POST")]
public class CreatePrivateCustomerRequest
{
    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "path", ExcludeInSchema = true)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "model")]
    public PrivateCustomer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and if you don't want the `PrivateCustomer` properties nested you would add them directly on the Request DTO, e.g:

```
[Route("/CreatePrivateCustomer/{UserId}", "POST")]
public class CreatePrivateCustomerRequest
{
    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "path", ExcludeInSchema = true)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see. Does this mean, that you can't define the operation to have both a header and body parameter? The UserId is only used for logging, and is not related to the object in the body, so I would rather not include it in the path.

Comment: In MVC this would be done like so:         PostPrivateCustomer([FromHeader]string userId, [FromBody]PrivateCustomer customer)

Comment: @ThomasNørgaard The first example shows a queryString, you can make it a Header but it won’t be populated on the DTO (you’d need to retrieve it from base.Request.Headers[“UserId”]), also many HTTP client library APIs don’t include support for HTTP Headers (or are in an environment where they’re restricted) and would require special treatment to support which would make APIs requiring custom headers cumbersome to deal with, so they should be avoided.